# How can create a View From Table that put ROWS in COLUMNS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to create a complex View from these tables.

**Table1:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RRSlotFiltriXDatiAggregatiElaborati](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IdRRSlotFiltri] [int] NOT NULL,
    [idParametro] [int] NULL,
    [idUm] [int] NULL,
    [valore] [decimal](8, 3) NULL,
    [idTipoElaborazione] [int] NULL,
    [idTipoParametro] [int] NULL,
    [idAggregazione] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_RRSlotXElaborazioniFD] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)
```

Now in this table, I have this values:
[image]

Now, as you can see for every parameter (id= 11|12|13), in my table there are 5 records. The records are different by idUm , idAggregazione.

Now I want to create a View that from this table have 3 rows, 1 for every parameter (11,12,13) and other 5 columns (column Valore) so this should to be the output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use dynamic SQL in a VIEW, but if you have a known or maximum number of items, it becomes a simple matter of using Row_Number() and a PIVOT.

**Example**

```
Select *
 From  (
        Select idParameter
              ,Item  = concat('valore',row_number() over(partition by idParameter order by id)
              ,value = valore
         From  [dbo].[RRSlotFiltriXDatiAggregatiElaborati]
       ) src
 Pivot (max(value) for Item in ( [valore1],[valore2],[valore3],[valore4],[valore5] ) ) pvt
```

Comment: Your query not return the output that I want. your query return 8 rows but I want 3 rows and 5 column for the values.

Comment: @bircastri I suspect you have 8 distinct values for idParameter .   Based on the image of sample data, it should have returned 3 rows and 5 columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` & do conditional aggregation :

```
create view v1 as
    select idParameter, 
           max(case when seq = 1 then valore end) as valore1,
           max(case when seq = 2 then valore end) as valore2,
           max(case when seq = 3 then valore end) as valore3,
           max(case when seq = 4 then valore end) as valore4,
           max(case when seq = 5 then valore end) as valore5
    from (select r.*,
                 row_number() over (partition by idParameter order by id) as seq
          from [dbo].[RRSlotFiltriXDatiAggregatiElaborati] r
         ) r
    group by idParameter;
```